# How to write query to make a data divide into parts for same id

Tags: mysql

Here i like to explain my problem

Here i have a table like this

```
Company_name employee_id name    dob      father_name  father_dob  mother_name  mother_dob
TCS          EMP1201     Kalai  13/11/92  Mahendran    13/11/86    Amutha       15/7/88
CTS          EMP1202     Naveen 13/11/92  raman        13/11/86    seetha       15/7/88
TCS          EMP1203     Ganesh 13/11/92  Viijay       13/11/86    Sangetha     15/7/88
```

i need to write a query to show the father_name and father_dob seperately for employee_id belongs

same thing for mother_name and mother_dob too

i want to get a table like this,

```
 employee_id name       dob
 EMP1201     Kalai      13/11/91
 EMP1201        Mahendran  13/11/86    
 EMP1201     Amutha     15/7/88
```

so how can i write select query for this scenario.

Comment: Use `UNION`  and order it by `employee_id`

Comment: can you give me query pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION` and finally order it by `employee_id`.

**Query**

```
select * from
(
    select employee_id,name,dob
    from table_name
    union
    select employee_id,father_name,father_dob
    from table_name
    union
    select employee_id,mother_name,mother_dob
    from table_name
)t
order by t.employee_id;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ae7a/2)

Update: If there is no(empty) father_name and father_dob,

```
select * from
(
    select employee_id,name,dob
    from table_name
    union
    select employee_id,father_name,father_dob
    from table_name 
    where father_name is not null and father_dob is not null
    union
    select employee_id,mother_name,mother_dob
    from table_name
    where mother_name is not null and mother_dob is not null
)t
order by t.employee_id;
```

[Check this fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4eefc/1)

Comment: Syntax error near ') order by t.employee_id t' at line 12   getting error

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it up now. There was an `Union` after the last selection.

Comment: how can i write condition if there is no(empty) father_name and father_dob

Comment: @ExCrin: Add a condition where both are not null in where clause.

Comment: pls give me to avoid empty father_name , father_dob, i tried but am getting error

Comment: pls see above i have updated my question, if i have a company_name how can i select company_name, can you give me a code pls

Comment: how i can retrieve data for tcs company alone

Comment: Give the condition in the where clause according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a union, something like:

```
SELECT employee_id, name,  dob
FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT employee_id, father_name,  dob
FROM YourTable
```

Order the final dataset as desired.